# Printing according to conditional

Tags: variable

I am using latex with `babel` and want to print the following, but within the context of a variable being set.  What can I do?

```
\begin{otherlanguage}{french}

  La Nuit Magique

  cédille Ç

  accent aigu é

  accent circonflexe â, ê, î, ô, û,

  accent grave à, è, ù

  accent tréma ë, ï, ü

\end{otherlanguage}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *within the context of a variable being set*?

Comment: I want to use a variable that determines whether the text is printed or not.

Comment: For this case it's better to use `otherlanguage*` rather than `otherlanguage`.

Comment: The question is not about `otherlanguage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to set a boolean, that determines if the french text is shown or not. I added a toggle `show french` for that purpose (see code below).

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english, french]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\newtoggle{show french}
\toggletrue{show french} % comment this line to hide french text

some english text \dots

\iftoggle{show french}{
    \begin{otherlanguage}{french}
      La Nuit Magique
    
      cédille Ç
    
      accent aigu é
    
      accent circonflexe â, ê, î, ô, û,
    
      accent grave à, è, ù
    
      accent tréma ë, ï, ü
    \end{otherlanguage}
}{}

some english text \dots

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is  `etoolbox`  built-in for `texlive`?

Comment: `etoolbox` is contained by texlive under `texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox`.